# layoutsubviews not called when iPhone rotated upsidedown at one time

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, layoutsubviews

I'm making a function using Camera(AVCapture input/output).
Now I have a trouble like below.

'layoutSubviews' is not called when iPhone is rotated upsidedown(180 degree) at one time.
(If rotate in 2 step 90 degree and 90 degree, 'layoutSubviews' is called in each rotation)

I'm using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to display camera output.
And to rotate the preview layer, I wrote the code like below.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];   
    [_previewLayer setFrame:self.bounds];
    [self setVideoOrientation];
}

- (void)setVideoOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    AVCaptureVideoOrientation videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;

    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [_previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:videoOrientation];
}
```

Could you please tell me, if you know, a good solution to call 'layoutSubviews' in 180 degree rotation at one time.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think layoutSubviews just be called when main view is updated frame. I think you can try to 'resize' or refresh main view frame when device rotate first.

Comment: @MụcĐồng Thanks. The view is main view (Set by `setView` in `loadView` method of ViewController). So `layourSubviews` is called in 90 degree rotatoin.  I'd like to know how to call `laytoutSubviews` in 180 degree rotation.

Comment: Now I took a workaround. Call `[self.view setNeedsLayout;` in ViewController's `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`.  Maybe it's not best solution but works correctly so far.